# Implementing a dictionary in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to implement a dictionary using lists in Common Lisp. The program is supposed to take a list of words and create a word histogram with frequency of each unique word.

This is the program:

```
(defparameter *histo* '())

(defun scanList (list)
  (loop for word in list
     do (if (assoc word histo)
            ((setf pair (assoc word histo))
             (remove pair histo)
             (setf f (+ 1 (second pair)))
             (setf pair ((car pair) f))
             (append histo pair))
            ((setf pair (word '1)) (append histo pair)))))
```

The error I get is: `(SETF PAIR (ASSOC WORD *HISTO*)) should be a lambda expression`.

Where is the syntax or semantic error exactly ?

```
(defun scanList (list the fox jumped over the other fox))
(princ *histo*)
```

Comment: I don't know Lisp but generally dictionaries are implemented with hash tables, not lists

Comment: And why you don't use hash-tables which are already dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

The posted code has a whole lot of problems. The reported error is caused by superfluous parentheses. Parentheses can't be added arbitrarily to expressions in Lisps without causing problems. In this case, these are the offending expressions:

```
((setf pair (assoc word histo))
 (remove pair histo)
 (setf f (+ 1 (second pair)))
 (setf pair ((car pair) f)
 (append histo pair))

((setf pair (word '1)) (append histo pair))
```

In both of these expressions, the results of the calls to `setf` are placed in the function position of a list, so the code attempts to call that result as if it is a function, leading to the error.

There are other issues. It looks like OP code is trying to pack expressions into the arms of an `if` form; this is probably the origin of the extra parentheses noted above. But, `if` forms can only take a single expression in each arm. You can wrap multiple expressions in a `progn` form, or use a `cond` instead (which does allow multiple expressions in each arm). There are some typos: `*histo*` is mistyped as `histo` in most of the code; `f` and `pair` are not defined anyplace; `(setf pair (word '1))` quotes the `1` unnecessarily (which will work, but is semantically wrong).

Altogether, the code looks rather convoluted. This can be made much simpler, still following the same basic idea:

```
(defparameter *histo* '())

(defun build-histogram (words)
  (loop :for word :in words
        :if (assoc word *histo*)
          :do (incf (cdr (assoc word *histo*)))
        :else
          :do (push (cons word 1) *histo*)))
```

This code is almost self-explanatory. If a `word` has already been added to `*histo*`, increment its counter. Otherwise add a new entry with the counter initialized to 1. This code isn't ideal, since it uses a global variable to store the frequency counts. A better solution would construct a new list of frequency counts and return that:

```
(defun build-histogram (words)
  (let ((hist '()))
    (loop :for word :in words
          :if (assoc word hist)
            :do (incf (cdr (assoc word hist)))
          :else
            :do (push (cons word 1) hist))
    hist))
```

Of course, there are all kinds of other ways you might go about solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Use hash-table for creating the dictionary and then transform to an association-list (alist) to sort it by key or value.

```
(defun build-histo (l)
  (let ((dict (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
    (loop for word in l
          do (incf (gethash word dict))
          finally (return dict))))

;; which was simplification (by @Renzo) of
;; (defun build-histo (l)
;;   (let ((dict (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
;;     (loop for word in l
;;           for count = (1+ (gethash word dict 0))
;;           do (setf (gethash word dict) count)
;;           finally (return dict))))

(defparameter *histo* (build-histo '("a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b")))

(defun hash-table-to-alist (ht)
  (maphash #'(lambda (k v) (cons k v)) ht))

;; which is the same like:
;; (defun hash-table-to-alist (ht)
;;   (loop for k being each hash-key of ht
;;         for v = (gethash k ht)
;;         collect (cons k v)))


;; sort the alist ascending by value
(sort (hash-table-to-alist *histo*) #'< :key #'cdr)
;; => (("c" . 1) ("a" . 3) ("b" . 4))

;; sort the alist descending by value
(sort (hash-table-to-alist *histo*) #'> :key #'cdr)
;; => (("b" . 4) ("a" . 3) ("c" . 1))

;; sort the alist ascending by key
(sort (hash-table-to-alist *histo*) #'string< :key #'car)
;; => (("a" . 3) ("b" . 4) ("c" . 1))

;; sort the alist descending by key
(sort (hash-table-to-alist *histo*) #'string> :eky #'car)
;; => (("c" . 1) ("b" . 4) ("a" . 3))
```

Comment: You can simplify the loop with `(loop for word in l  do (incf (gethash word dict 0))  finally (return dict))))`.